# How to use fonts for part of an expression in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 / Visual Studio 2008.

I have this displayed in the report

```
Date between  «Expr»
```

where <> is

```
format(Parameters!StartDate.Value,"MM/dd/yy") & " and " & format(Parameters!EndDate.Value,"MM/dd/yy")
```

I want to display the actual dates in different font/size/color. Or the " and " in a different font/size/color.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create several text boxes with different formatting. Formatting parts of the text in the display via HTML or any other markup is not possible.

**EDIT**
Please note that HTML seems to be possible in SSRS 2012: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx